# What is the meaning of "Trainwreck" title?

Tags: title, trainwreck

I saw the movie, there is no mention of train or something that is close related to the title.

Plot:Lead Actress make love to everyone she likes, but her relations screwed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the movie [Trainwreck](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3152624/) with [Amy Schumer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2154960/).  The name is based off of the phrase "[train wreck](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/train-wreck)," which is basically a person that doesn't have their life together, or their life is a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of

***Train wreck*** : 
**Someone who is in a terrible situation, someone who is a disaster.**

Accordingly the Title is perfect for the movie as in the movie we see Amy is a true jerk. She’s selfish. She’s rude.and these all nature always led her to terrible situations and which gives her persona of being a disaster.